# Using Cypress cy.get() with a contains selector not working as expected

Tags: jquery-selectors, cypress

I am trying to use a selector in Cypress to be able to find the data in my web page. It doesn't seem to be working as I expect, but it might just be that I'm not understanding the way it's supposed to work.

I am doing the following. The `click()` is just so I could see if the `cy.get()` worked, I'm trying to find the right selector. I will eventually be using the selector in a complex `cy.contains()`, I'm trying to build from the ground up.

```
cy.get('body:contains(ATHLETE FIRST NAME)').click();
```

I have an element that has the above text in two places. But the `contains()` above doesn't seem to be finding it, but it doesn't cause a failure.

If I change that line to:

```
cy.get('div:contains(ATHLETE FIRST NAME)').click();
```

It tells me it found that 12 times. It seems as though it is only finding the `body` or `div`, but totally ignoring the `:contains()`. I'm thinking I must be doing this wrong, but one example I found seems to be doing it this way, and can't find many examples at all.

==========

UPDATE 2020-06-08

I'm switching gears on this.

Here's what my code is doing, from the Cypress UI logs. I'm no longer using the `:contains()` selector, I'm using `name` instead:

```
contains [name=customerFirstName], johnie
```

Here is the element that is displayed at the time:

```
<input aria-invalid="false" id="outlined-name" name="customerFirstName" type="text"
       class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input" value="johnie"
       style="...">
```

It is not finding that `value`, even though it's in the element that should be selected by the `name`.
I even tried searching on `'#outlined-name'`, but it made no difference.

Comment: if you want you have an option to start using Xpath instead of CSS, cypress supported Xpath as well

Comment: Could you post the full `html` of that section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WRT to your update, for getting the value of an input field please see

[How do I get an input’s value?](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq.html#How-do-I-get-an-input%E2%80%99s-value)

```
cy.get('[name=customerFirstName]')
  .should('have.value', 'johnie');
```

OR

```
cy.get('[name=customerFirstName]')
  .invoke('val')
  .should('eq', 'johnie');
```

The `contains(selector, content)` command is only for elements with content between the opening and closing tags, which is applicable to `<div>`,  `<span>` etc but not `<input />` which is self-closing.

Answer (score 0):

`:contains()` is not getting ignored but cypress is considering `:contains()` for all the `parent <div>` as well.
And since `click` event can be triggered by cypress on a single element by default you are seeing the error in the second case.

Consider this template:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>ATHLETE FIRST NAME</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

`cy.get('body:contains(ATHLETE FIRST NAME)').click()` will return the `body` element which is a single element so there will be no error.

but

`cy.get('div:contains(ATHLETE FIRST NAME)').click()`

will return 3 `div` elements so you will see this error:

> cy.click() can only be called on a single element. Your subject
>   contained 3 elements. Pass { multiple: true } if you want to serially
>   click each element.

Comment: Thanks, @Sree.Bh! So does this mean that I can't use `:contains()` to narrow the focus to a particular element?

Comment: Can you try `cy.contains('div', 'ATHLETE FIRST NAME').click()` if the other element which contains "ATHLETE FIRST NAME" is not a `div`.

Comment: I'm switching gears here, please see my update at the end of the original post above. It's too hard to put formatted data into comments.

Comment: @Westy: How does your `cy.get` statement looks like to select the `input` element, please add that too. And you can try: `cy.get('[name=customerFirstName]').should('have.value', 'johnie')`